# PHP SoapClient Returns SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL when loading local webservice

Tags: php, reporting-services, xampp, soap-client

I am trying to call SoapClient on local installation of SSRS.  It is failing and returning:

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '`http://localhost:8080/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl`'

I can put the url '`http://localhost:8080/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl`' in browser and it displays the XML WSDL as expected.

Also the call to file_get_contents using the above url fails

My environment is Windows 7 using XAMPP.

I believe XAMPP web server cannot access that file/location.

in hosts file I put:

127.0.0.1    localhost:8080/ReportServer

in httpd-vhosts.conf I put in:

```
   NameVirtualHost *
     <VirtualHost *>
       DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\SBSProductionDatabase"
       ServerName localhost
     </VirtualHost>
     <VirtualHost *>
       DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer"
       ServerName localhost:8080/ReportServer
     <Directory "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer">
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
     </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

where "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer" is the location of the file ReportExecution2005.asmx

What am I doing wrong?

BTW, my call is:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8080/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl",
                         array('login' => "domain\userid",
                               'password' => "password"));
```

Comment: The Full warning I get is:

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://localhost:8080/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://localhost:8080/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl" in C:\xampp\htdocs\SBSProductionDatabase\SSRS\GetReports.php:61 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SBSProductionDatabase\SSRS\GetReports.php(61): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://localhos...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SBSProductionDatabase\SSRS\GetReports.php on line 61

Comment: i have a problem like you had, could check if you can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259178/uncaught-soapfault-exception-wsdl-soap-error-parsing-wsdl

Answer (score 0):

So, what happens when you browse "localhost:8080/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl" or just 'localhost:8080/ReportServer' in browser ?

Comment: it works.  the xml wsdl is shown as expected and for just the url I get the SSRS Report Server page/site

Comment: Have you tried following tested sample ?http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/05/04/getting-started-with-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-and-php.aspx

Comment: Yes.  basically I am trying to call new SSRSReport(new Credentials(UID, PWD), SERVICE_URL);, which will eventually try to call SoapClient as I have above.  The call to SSRSReport fails, because of SoapClient() fails.  And I see the underlining problem is that XAMPP is not configured to access the SSRS web site locally on my machine

Comment: That rings a bell. Try Method 2 mentioned at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861 and bounce your machine once before you re-try. If this does not help, Follow this KB to enable verbose and HTTP logging on RS side, lets see if the request is even reaching the RS process \http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2146315

Comment: I am using XAMPP, not IIS.  So would your suggestions work for me?

Comment: Not sure but DisableLoopBackCheck is not IIS specific. It can restrict any two process on Windows OS talking to each other locally on same box over NTLM auth. I'd say, if you are on Windows, Give it a shot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34499/discussion-between-ron5504-and-larry)

Comment: could you check if you can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259178/uncaught-soapfault-exception-wsdl-soap-error-parsing-wsdl